# How to handle Next and Previous button for similar of tab contents

Tags: jquery

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/fpjyyyfq/). You can see that if anyone click link `B`, that's content open, if click `C` that's content open hiding the previous opened just like jQuery tab. Now, I want the same action for `Next` and `Previous` button. But, I can't write the script correctly. The way I has tried/got error/can't write correctly:

```
$('body').on('click', '.next', function() {  
   var nextId = $('.div-link li.active').next().find('li a').attr('href');  // I don't understand how can I get the next id of opened div
   $('.div-link li' +nextId).addClass('active');  // I even can't imagine how can be set the active class at the li links
});
```

I am not good at jQuery. So, please help me writing the script for clicking on `Next` and `Previous` button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and messy way would be:

```
$('.back').click(function(){
    $('.div-link .active').prev().children('a').click();
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    $('.div-link .active').next().children('a').click();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fpjyyyfq/2/)

Comment: @user1896653 my bad... meant to put `.children()` instead of `.child()`... always confuse those. I updated the answer. The jsFiddle worked when I made that change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKNkn/49/) for reference with next and  previous buttons

```
...  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();        
    $("#prevBtn").bind("click", prevOfferTab);
    $("#nextBtn").bind("click", nextOfferTab);
});
...

function nextOfferTab() {
    console.log('nxt');
    var newTabIndex = parseInt(getSelectedTabIndex(1));
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', newTabIndex);
}

function prevOfferTab() {
    var newTabIndex = parseInt(getSelectedTabIndex(-1));
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', newTabIndex);
}
```